# Nginx - proxy to Node.js and PHP

Tags: nginx

I would like that *www.example.com* jumps to Node application and that www.example.com/administration jumps to php.
Here is current config file for example.com page:

```
# the configuration file
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log warn;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /administration {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/example.com/administration/index.html;

      auth_basic "Restricted Content";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      auth_basic "Restricted Content";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

It works for www.example.com (starts Node application), but I don't know how to set a PHP part.

Answer (score 1):

Other than setting the `try_files` and basic HTTP auth, you have not configured anything for the `/administration` location block. You should tell nginx to pass the request to a PHP interpreter like php-fpm. The most common way to do this is to just pass any request to a request that ends with `.php` to the PHP interpreter, like so:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

The value of `fastcgi_pass` might differ on your system. It could be a different socket, it could be a TCP port, like `127.0.0.1:9000` (which is also fairly common). It depends on your setup, but there's not enough information in your question to tell what it should be in your case.